# Editing AndroidManifest.xml using config.xml for Phonegap Build to make app tablet only

Tags: android, xml, phonegap-build, tablet

I'm struggling to make an app for Android using Phonegap that is only accessible on tablets. My understanding is that I need to ask Phonegap Build to modify the outputted AndroidManifest.xml.

I have tried adding the following code to config.xml, but it doesn't seem to be doing the trick:

```
    <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/*" mode="merge">
    <supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
                    android:smallScreens="false"
                    android:normalScreens="true"
                    android:largeScreens="true"
                    android:xlargeScreens="true"
                    android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Could anyone tell what what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Nick

Answer (score 1):

try this instead:

```
<config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="merge">
     <supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" />
</config-file>
```

No need to set anything to "true" as that is the default.

Also this bit, copied from the docs is **key**

> Important: When targeting Android with the config-file element, you'll
>   need to declare the android xml namespace in the widget element of
>   your config.xml, otherwise your document will not pass our xml
>   validation. xml

I cant paste the rest as my rep is less than 10 - see the docs and look for the above passage and read the part that follows it:

http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/config-file-element/

I got this to work just now in my PGB project for other manifesty things i needed to change